# Spring 3 class to hold and return a single bean instance?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Let's say I have a spring bean I want to use through out my application, but because it's legacy code I can't make every single class I want to use it in a `@Component` or any kind of bean because the class is being manually instantiated through out the project, so I can't just @Autowire it where I want it.

How can I create a wrapper class for a spring bean I want to reuse configured as below, so that it will do nothing other than return the instance of the bean registered on the application context?

```
@Service("myBean")
public class MyBean {
```

Basically I'm looking for something like `MyBeanHolder.java` with a method like:

```
public MyBean getGlobalInstance() {
     //return my global instance of MyBean
}
```

So this way, anywhere I want to use MyBean, I can fetch the instance via this `getGlobalInstance()` method.

How can I achieve this running Spring 3.X?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your method `getGlobalInstance` is in the class, which is also a spring bean, you can do this:

```
class MyBeanHolder {
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public MyBean getGlobalInstance() {
    return applicationContext.getBean(MyBean.class);
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can implement the interface `ApplicationContextAware` to get the application context, where you can find you bean with `getBean`

Comment: So basically, the route of implementing ApplicationContextAware is the only way to go, because if I make this class a bean, then I'm still left with the issue where now I can't wire in THIS new class because where I'm trying to use it are still non-bean classes that is legacy code I can't change? Right?